# using data- attributes will affect the performance of the application?

Tags: javascript, performance

i am planning to use data- attributes to identify elements in DOM for selenium test cases. Will the usage of attributes affects application performance?

Comment: compared to not using them and using only css which may change drastically in the future. I want to know whether application slows down if i use lots data-attributes

Comment: @Amareswar: What do `data-` attributes have to do with CSS?

Comment: @Rocket, i am planning to use data- attributes instead of using css classes while finding an element

Comment: @Amareswar: Classes would definitely be faster if you're selecting elements.

Comment: A more formal answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15010727/1559840

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all, you'll be fine with using `data-*` attributes. However, you should note that using the syntax `$.data(theInput, 'someData');` is much faster than using the syntax `theInput.data('someData');`, as demonstrated in this [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-attr/2).

Comment: The link you posted only compares the various was to get data attributes. However, according to http://jsperf.com/class-vs-data-attribute-selector-performance it seems that get dom elements using data attributes instead of css selectors is about 98% slower!